# Summing factors of binomial coefficients - get general formula?

Tags: function-construction, combinatorics, sequence

Consider summing more and more factors of binomial coefficients:

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n > 0, Sum[Binomial[n, i] // FunctionExpand, {i, 1, n}]] // FullSimplify
```

> `-1 + 2^n`

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n > 0, Sum[Binomial[n, i] Binomial[n - i, j] // FunctionExpand, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n - i}]] // FullSimplify
```

> `1 - 2^(1 + n) + 3^n`

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n > 0, Sum[Binomial[n, i] Binomial[n - i, j] Binomial[n - i - j, k] //FunctionExpand, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n - i}, {k, 1, n - i - j}]] // FullSimplify
```

> `-1 + 3 2^n - 3^(1 + n) + 4^n`

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n > 0, Sum[Binomial[n, i] Binomial[n - i, j] Binomial[n - i - j, k] Binomial[n - i - j - k, l] // FunctionExpand, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n - i}, {k, 1, n - i - j}, {l, 1, n - i - j - k}]] // FullSimplify
```

> `1 - 2^(2 + n) + 2 3^(1 + n) - 4^(1 + n) + 5^n`

We can see that in each case the result is a sum over integers to the power `n` with some coefficients. Now I wonder if there is a way to use *Mathematica* to get the general expression for an arbitrary number of factors of binomial coefficients? (Continuing the above sequence all the way up to `n` factors of binomial coefficients under `n` sums.)

Comment: Oh, I'm silly... Seems like the coefficients are just binomial coefficients, power is always the same and sign is alternating...

Comment: Perhaps you should self-answer, or if you do not feel motivated to do so, delete this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By inspection of the first few terms we can infer that the correct generalization should be:

```
fun[m_, n_] := Sum[(-1)^(q + m) Binomial[m - 1, q - 1] q^n, {q, 1, m}]
```

which properly reproduces the results:

```
Table[fun[m, n], {m, 2, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]